# Expressing contentment about receiving a letter

Tags: letter-writing, formality

Someone wrote to me. I'm writing him back. I want to say, in formal speech, that I'm glad that he wrote to me. How do I do that? I guess I can just say "I'm glad to hear from you" but maybe you could suggest a more elegant expression.

Comment: As an aside, the way your title is constructed would require [contentment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contentment) rather than 'content', though that would still sound rather contrived.

Comment: Thanks! Would you suggest a more appropriate word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- I am glad to receive your letter.
- I was happy to read your letter.
- Thank you for your kind/informative/helpful letter.